# From chemfig to .mol file/SMILES

Tags: molecular-structure, structural-formula

I usually draw molecules using the markup language known as `LaTeX`. In particular, I use the [chemfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package. I much prefer this method over WYSIWYG apps because it allows me a greater degree of customization.
Yes, I know [this package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mol2chemfig) can generate structure from .mol and SMILES files. I'd like to know: is it possible to follow the reverse path, i.e. once the structure has been drawn with chemfig, generate the .mol file and/or the SMILES?

Comment: I'm not sure how much chemistry is in the chemfig descriptions, but if a machine can understand it, it probably can convert it. It you are working off an image alone, then some kind of pattern recognition is needed. I'm sure there's going to be a tool for that. There might already be a question on this platform about this.

Comment: Working backwards is not always easy (actually, rarely) but my guess is it might not be so hard to look at a chemfig text file and interpret the commands to generate a molecule in mol format. SMILES might be harder but a format that generates bonds based on proximity should be doable. You'll need programming experience, a library of standard bond lengths (or rather ranges), and some geometry commands to rotate atoms in space.

Comment: Maybe just the task for ML.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is a definitively *yes there are* programs to scan papers with the aim to retrieve chemical information from the illustrations.  One of them is OSRA hosted by NIH ([project landing page](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/osra/)) with a [demo page](https://cactus.nci.nih.gov/cgi-bin/osra/index.cgi) (requires JavaScript enabled); below with a a «glucose»* structure from the ChemFig's manual (French edition provided [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig), version 1.6e/June 30th, 2023, p. 42) submitted as .png (322 x 223 px, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced)

[image]

(screen photo of NIH' OSRA)

to retrieve SMILES and .sdf about glucose (here: the program corrected the OH/HO bonding issue, but there is no stereochemistry retained).  It isn't the only player in the field (e.g. [ChemOCR](https://www.scai.fraunhofer.de/en/business-research-areas/bioinformatics/products/chemocr.html)) and there are multiple references in the literature (below just about OSRA and a more recent review).  Think about digitization of printed journals and patents to build literature databases and machine learning as potential fields of application.

Some of the potential pitfalls are *conceptual similar* to the ones encountered with OCR on text: prior use, there is need for training; and low input quality requires some sort of correction. See for example the adrenaline structure by the same manual, page 43, captured as 330x200 px .png

[image]

vs an input of better quality based on Wikipedia's depiction of [α-tocopherol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91-Tocopherol) (default .png, upper part of the [property box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91-Tocopherol#/media/File:Tocopherol,_alpha-.svg)):

[image]

*Better input quality* can be any combination of file type (e.g., png vs gif), is the figure a color/half-tone/black-and-white illustration, presence/absence of background, the optical resolution, font type used, etc.

---

* Personal note: I once was a user of ChemFig but glitches like the bonding of an hydroxyl group to the back bone *via* H instead of *O* a sketcher *can* warn you while constructing the formula was a reason to step away.  A second one is that ChemFig's input format, though documented, is not used widely enough (in my perception vs .cdxml, .sdf, .mol, .mol2, etc.) by other programs (other editors and viewers, databases, programs like RDKit and openbabel, etc) to ease *quick* and *reliable* and *smooth exchange* with colleagues.  (True, if it were used by many, more programs would support the format.)  It is one thing to write a thesis / prepare a presentation with much time to tinker on your own vs. the fast paced interaction with your in colleagues (possibly not so much aware of LaTeX, especially in organic chemistry [I know, it is a stereotype ... no pun intended]) on the bench.  But have a look on [chemobabel](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemobabel).

So yes, I'm on the lazy side here to assemble the structure / reaction and apply one of the Journal's *style sheets* (e.g. ACS, RSC for one or two columns, Wiley, HCA) many editors ship with by default / a house style the group adopted.  Or substitute it by an other as after a few mouse clicks *every* label and bond is reset *consistently*.  (It can go south and corrupt alignments, but this is corrected quickly via the editor's GUI.)  The export of the illustration in a vector format (.svg, .[e]ps, .pdf) is supported for long by many editors (see [Gunda's review](https://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/)).  The synchronization of labeling numbers below the compounds in the illustration and the LaTeX based compuscript can be addressed for instance with temporary labels in [chemscheme](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemscheme), too.

(1) Filippov, I. V.; Nicklaus, M. C. Optical Structure Recognition Software To Recover Chemical Information: OSRA, An Open Source Solution. *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* **2009**, *49*, 740–743. [doi 10.1021/ci800067r.](https://doi.org/10.1021/ci800067r) and author's copy on [pubchem](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2889020/).

(2) Park, J.; Rosania, G. R.; Shedden, K. A.; Nguyen, M.; Lyu, N.; Saitou, K. Automated Extraction of Chemical Structure Information from Digital Raster Images. *Chem. Cent. J.* **2009**, *3*, 4. [doi 10.1186/1752-153X-3-4](https://doi.org/10.1186/1752-153X-3-4) and copy on [pubchem](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2648963/).

(3) Rajan, K.; Brinkhaus, H. O.; Zielesny, A.; Steinbeck, C. A Review of Optical Chemical Structure Recognition Tools. *J. Cheminform.* **2020**, *12*, 60. [doi 10.1186/s13321-020-00465-0](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-020-00465-0) (open access)